# Sql Like operator that matches a column with only multiple whitespaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a query with the 'like' operator that matches only text fields that contain multiple whitespaces and nothing more.
E.g. ' ','  ', '        ', etc. are string that should be found.
'    text   ', 'text  ' -- should not be included in the result set
(Sql Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, leading and trailing spaces are ignored for string comparisons.

That means you can just compare to an empty string to get your desired result:

`WHERE SomeVarchar = ''`

This will evaluate true even if SomeVarChar is a series of 20 spaces:

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE '                     ' = ''
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `RTRIM` or `LTRIM` and check against the empty string, however, as JNK pointed out, in SQL Server you can just check against the empty string and it will ignore the whitespace. [Here is a SQL fiddle that displays that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30d2e/2)

Code from fiddle

```
create table x ( y varchar(20))
insert into x values ('        ')
select 'TRUE' from x where y = ''
```

Comment: In SS you don't even need this, since leading/lagging whitespace is ignored in SS.

Comment: @MinMin there is jsfiddle.com for javascript/css/html